# Question on Firebase Authentication Identifier (Android)

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie Android developer. I are doing the Authentication of my APP. I have three questions under Firebase Authentication.

1. Given a registered user with a Firebase UID, is there any way to change from one identifier to another identifier without changing the UID under Firebase framework? For example, from phone# +852 23334444 to +852 56648999, or from phone# +852 23334444 to email abc@gmail.com.
2. Given a registered user with Firebase UID and with phone# +852 23334444 as identifier, can I assign another phone# +852 56648999 to the same UID under Firebase framework?
3. For two firebase UIDs with two phone# as identifier, can I group the two UIDs under firebase framework such that both UIDs will see the same data set in the real-time database?

It would be great if you can guide me to some documentations/github example for my further study. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can link multiple provider. Check here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Answer (score 1):

You can link multiple provider. Check here [firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking](http://You%20can%20link%20multiple%20provider.%20Check%20here%20firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking)

> 1. Given a registered user with a Firebase UID, is there any way to change from one identifier to another identifier without changing the UID under Firebase framework? For example, from phone# +852 23334444 to +852 56648999, or from phone# +852 23334444 to email abc@gmail.com.

After signin user, you can link other auth provider as you want.

Flow:

- Login with +852 23334444
- Change phone number and complete flow, then first unlink old provider (a) and link new provider (b)

> 2. Given a registered user with Firebase UID and with phone# +852 23334444 as identifier, can I assign another phone# +852 56648999 to the same UID under Firebase framework?

You can do as no.1 above, but you don't need to unlink your old provider (step a)

> 3. For two firebase UIDs with two phone# as identifier, can I group the two UIDs under firebase framework such that both UIDs will see the same data set in the real-time database?

There is no way you can group 2 UIDs. But you can design you real-time database to lookup to correct data that you want

Let's say user A has UID: **123**, user B: **456**. You need to mapping these UID to a unique ID that you store your data

```
userMapping: {
    123: {
        userId: abc
    },
    456: {
        userId: abc
    }
}

users: {
    abc: {
        name: 'User A',
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. it seems i can work around to achieve the goal. Thanks